# About C++ template and operators

Tags: c++, templates, operators

After some trial and a lot of error, I have come to find out that it is not very useful to template operators. As an Example:

```
class TemplateClass
{
  //Generalized template
  template<TType>
  TType& operator[](const std::string& key)
  {
    return TType;
  }
  //Specialized template for int
  template<>
  int& operator[]<int>(const std::string& key)
  {
    return 5;
  }
  //Specialized template for char
  template<>
  char& operator[]<char>(const std::string& key)
  {
    return 'a';
  }
}
int main()
{
  TemplateClass test;
  //this will not match the generalized template.
  test["test without template will fail"]; 
  //this is not how you call an operator with template.
  test<char>["test with template will fail"];
  //this works!
  test.operator[]<int>["test will work like this"];
  return 0;
}
```

So to make an operator with a template is pretty ugly (unless you are into verbose, and really who is?) This is why I have been using a function "get" in lieu of operators. My question is why the ugliness? Why is it required to include the operator key word. My guess is that it has to do with some back end magic of transforming operators to not use parentheses to take arguments, and is there any way around this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Trial and error, oh the time you could have saved had you read a book...

Comment: Note that if the operator takes an argument of the template parameter's type (like template<class T> int & operator[](const T & key) then the compiler can deduce the template argument from the argument you pass when you call it.

Comment: My question is WTF? Why are you even trying this? Specializations are to be avoided (if you can) and templatized operators should only be used if the compiler can figure out the template parameters via the template argument deduction rules. As for a C++ templates related book, I can recommend "C++ Templates -- The Complete Guide".

Comment: You're using operator overloading combined with function template specialization. That's [evil](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/evil-operator-overloading-of-the-day/) [squared](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). Don't do that.

Comment: @sellibitze: it has to be a template specialization, silly, because you can't overload on return type. ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Well, this code example is neither valid C++ nor looks like it's any useful. What I originally meant was that it is sometimes possible to "abstract some things away / defer things" so that you don't need specializations at this level. Still, even in this case you *could* do it without specializations, see http://codepad.org/dRxzmHqx. But I'm not actually proposing something stupid like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specifically an issue of templates. It's a grammar issue. What you're doing is odd in that you're only changing the return type. Had you changed the operator parameters, you wouldn't have to explicitly provide the type for the template. Since you do need to provide type, you need to explicitly call the operator to apply the parameter because it's the only way.

Check out the [grammar](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/c++std/cd2/gram.html) for complete details.

Comment: This. The grammar to differentiate `<>` template parameters from the comparison operators is gnarly.

Comment: I can only imagine it's an exercise in sadism.

Comment: You are right that this is just an exercise, 
and I did go hunting for some answers before putting 
code to keyboard. The project is a something like 
system directory; given a string path and data, 
create in memory the path and store the data. My 
approach was to make a class holding two trees, 
one for the data at the given level, and one for 
directories deeper than the current directory. 
A simple recursive exercise. I could easily have 
functions "getData" & "getDir", but since this 
is an exercise I felt like trying to actually make 
something more elaborate. 
oh well. :?

Comment: @Jericho Kain: Doing things in a 'clever' way like this lead to awful awful code. Never do this in practice. Make things simple and clear. It's better for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Return types cannot be used for overloading resolution.  The only difference in the signatures of your operator[] declarations is in their return types, so as soon as you had two of them, the compiler had no hope of disambiguating your call `test["test without template will fail"];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, template argument deduction is not working with function return types to be simple. However template operator overloading is really useful and can be applied in some completely tremendous ways.

Below there is a code sample from [boost::phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html).

```
for_each(c.begin(), c.end(),
    if_(arg1 % 2 == 1)
    [
        cout << arg1 << ' '
    ]
);
```

As you might understand it is an easy way to print out all the odd elements in a container. Kinda magic.